# Is to use parallel library calling XRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

In queries to XRM, is it helps to use the parallel extension library as so

```
xrm.AccountSet.AsParallel().Where(v=>v.ModifiedBy == DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault()
```

Instead of

```
xrm.AccountSet.Where(v=>v.ModifiedBy == DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault()
```

Or there is no difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how the XRM library converts LINQ to the Query Expressions but the Query Expressions have no concept of as parallel().  So I would guess that `xrm.AccountSet.AsParallel()` would have worse performance than `xrm.AccountSet.FirstOrDefault()`.

But in an effort to teach a man to fish rather than giving him one, read Eric Lippert's answer [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 0):

You must use `AsParallel()` after `AccountSet`.

For concrete example use

```
xrm.AccountSet.FirstOrDefault(v=>v.ModifiedBy == DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: This is not the point, the question is - Is the using of this library will make better performance?

Comment: First. You haven't notice in your question about performance. But answer about performance too.